# AlamoFire POST request is giving me an error using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, apple-push-notifications, alamofire

I have been successfully calling this function in order to send a push notification to users in my app. My backend is firebase and I'm using Xcode. For some reason as of today, it started throwing an error. Im new to AF so I am pretty confused on what to do.. I've searched S.O for answers, but none of the previous questions have solid answers. Please any help, thanks.

Here is the function

```
func sendPushNotification(device: String){

    let title = "Hey check this out"
    let body = "They're waiting on your response"

    let toDeviceID = device
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders()

    headers = ["content_type":"application/json", "Authorization":"key=\(AppDelegate.SERVER_KEY)"]

    let notification = ["to":"\(toDeviceID)", "notification":["body":body, "title":title, "badge":1, "sound":"default"]] as [String:Any]

    AF.request(AppDelegate.NOTIFICATION_URL as URLConvertible, method: .post as HTTPMethod, parameters: notification, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

    }
}
```

The error I am getting is,

> **failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))**

Comment: This error means the response you are getting is not a valid JSON. Try to use `responseData { (data) in` instead of `responseJSON { (response) in` and print `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` to see the actual response.

Comment: @Kamran thanks for the reply, will try that right now and let you know

Comment: @Kamran - this is the response that i received - ("Error=DeprecatedEndpoint")

Comment: So you need to update the `endPoint` used in this url `AppDelegate.NOTIFICATION_URL`.  You might have to look into the documentation to get the new endPoint.

Comment: @Kamran, its easier to use `responseString` instead of `responseData`, because with responseString you don't need to encode to string, just simply `print(response)` after `.responseString { (response) in`

Comment: @Kamran I refreshed the server key (which is that notification URL) that i received from Firebase Cloud messaging.. However, i still get the same error.. I have no clue of any other way to update the endpoint that im passing in.

Comment: @Kamran Hey you were right! I found the new endpoint that google changed.. thanks a ton i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As directed by @kamran - the issue was that the Firebase endpoint had been replaced.. If anybody ever has the issue in the future, id definitely go check the firebase docs..

Problematic Endpoint = https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Resolved Endpoint = https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Once again - this is using firebase cloud messaging to send push notifications

Comment: It will be better if you can update your answer with problematic and new endpoint for  new readers to easily fix the issue.

Comment: @Kamran will do now